# Rewrite Rule in .htaccess not working With MAC OS

Tags: php, macos, apache, .htaccess

Hi Friends i wrote rewrite rule for my website in PHP, Its working Fine with windows and Linux os But i moved this project to MAC OSX at that time is goes error and not rewrite that properly

The .htaccess file code is given below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ProjectName

RewriteRule uploads/(.*)  uploads/$1 [L]
RewriteRule css/(.*)  css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule libs/(.*)  libs/$1 [L]
RewriteRule js/(.*)  js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule images/(.*)  images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule Files/(.*)  Files/$1 [L]
RewriteRule API/(.*)  API/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php?module=$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)$ index.php?module=$1&action=$2 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?module=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

Required any help from your side

Thanx Guyzzz...

Answer (score 0):

No idea how you got this to work on any OS as the last set of rules will never get applied.

First, your 3 conditions only ever get applied to the immediately following rule, so only `RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php?module=$1 [L]`. That means the last two rules have no conditions, which happens to be *OK* because they never get used anyways. The `RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php?module=$1 [L]` rule's pattern matches everything and thus the last two rules are redundant. What you're probably after is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?module=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)$ index.php?module=$1&action=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php?module=$1 [L]
```